# Apaxy Parent Directory on root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have Apaxy (https://oupala.github.io/apaxy/) on my subfolder **downloads**.

```
www.example.com/work/downloads/
```

Everything is working OK, but when I'm in this subfolder and click on **Parent Directory**, I get redirected to `www.example.com/work/` and it is not desirable.

How I can disable it?

Comment: This is using mod_autoindex functionality, so I'd try adding an `IndexIgnore` directive for the parent directory `..` first. If that does not work, then check the structure of the generated HTML, and find a way to hide that parent directory link via custom CSS maybe.

Comment: When I use: IndexIgnore .htaccess /theme .. so I lost option Parent Directory in subfolders, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the parent `.htaccess` file, (in either `/.htaccess` (root) or `/work/.htaccess`) disable mod_autoindex directory listings.

For example:

```
Options -Indexes
```

When you click on the "parent directory", it will still navigate to `/work/`, but you will get a 403 Forbidden response instead of a directory listing.

---

**UPDATE#1:** You could redirect any requests for `/work/` (directory only) to `/work/downloads/` - so the user is always redirected back when they click on "Parent Directory" from the downloads directory.

For example, in `/work/.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/work/$ /work/downloads/
```

Alternatively, if you only want to redirect the user back to `/work/downloads/` when they are navigating from `/work/downloads/` then you can use mod_rewrite and check the `Referer` header on the request. (Assuming you are permitting the full `Referer` header to be passed internally. Although this is still user dependent.)

For example, in `/work/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/work/downloads/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /work/downloads/ [R,L]
```

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> When I use: `IndexIgnore .htaccess /theme ..` so I lost option Parent Directory in subfolders, too.

You could try to restrict `IndexIgnore` to the `/work/downloads/` directory only. For example (requires Apache 2.4):

```
# DOES NOT WORK!
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/work/downloads/'">
    IndexIgnore ..
</If>
```

However, this does not work! The `<If>` expression changes the order of processing (it is *merged* very late). My guess is that it is processed too late for mod_autoindex.

Comment: yes, I have this status now that when it redirects me there, I get the voice "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource." 

it is possible to set it in work/.htaccess from the browser so that it immediately clicks on /work/download

Comment: You could redirect the user from `/work/` to `/work/downloads/`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MichalAB I've updated my answer again with an alternative rule that checks the `Referer` header. So should only redirect users that navigate from the `downloads` subdirectory - back to the `downloads` subdirectory.

Comment: @MichalAB I've updated my answer again - to restrict `IndexIgnore` to the `downloads` directory only.

Comment: @MichalAB Update... I missed the trailing slash from the last rule!

Comment: <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/work/downloads/'">
    IndexIgnore ..
</If>

This if it worked it would be fine but it doesn't work. 
I still see the parent directory there at www.domain.com/work/download

Comment: @MichalAB Hhhmm, yes, the `<If>` expression does not work unfortunately. The `<If>` expression changes the order of processing. My guess is that this is processed too late for it to influence mod_autoindex. (?)

Comment: And is there no solution to this problem?